# Laravel 4 auto inserting </form>

Tags: forms, laravel

I updated Laravel 4.1 recently and an exiting modal window form is not working correctly. I have figured out that for some reason after the Laravel 4.1 update, Laravel is auto inserting an  tag into my modal body. (I have the Form::close() in the footer. I was just curious if anyone else has seen this or can offer an explanation of why this is happening and how to prevent it. I am good about searching through my issues, but this one is not yielding me any results.

Note that if I move my submit button into the modal-body div, then submit works as expected and updates goes through the normal process.. but for some reason with this particular modal, having the submit button in the footer puts the submit button outside of the form as the form close is auto inserted before the end of the modal-body div. Also strangely enough I have this working on another page, and everything works as expected.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<div class="modal-body">

            <?php
                $access = Session::get('user_access'); 
                $userid = Session::get('user_id');
            ?>

            {{ Form::open(array('method'=>'POST','route' => 'users.store', 'style' => 'display:inline')) }}

            @foreach($user as $userinfo)

                <!-- Set hidden form element with userid embedded -->
                <input type="hidden" name='id' id='id' value={{ $userid }}>


                <!-- Display the username and profile Picture -->
                <h2><center>{{ $userinfo->username }}</center></h2>
                <br><br>

                <!-- 2 Column Form to change user information and display current status -->
                <div class ='container col-md-offset-1'>
                    <div class='row col-md-3'>
                        <div>
                            {{ Form::label('givenname', 'First Name:') }} <br>
                            <input type="text" name='givenname' id='givenname' value={{ $userinfo->givenname }}>
                        </div><br />

                        <div>
                            {{ Form::label('surname', 'Last Name:') }} <br>
                            <input type="text" name='surname' id='surname' value={{ $userinfo->surname }}>
                        </div><br />


                        <div>
                            {{ Form::label('email', 'Email Address:') }} <br>
                            <input type="text" name='email' id='email' value={{ $userinfo->email }}>
                        </div><br />
                    </div>

                    <div class='row col-md-3'>
                        <div>
                            {{ Form::label('password', 'New Password:') }} <br>
                            <input type="password" name='password' id='password' value={{ $userinfo->password }}>
                        </div><br />

                        <div>
                            {{ Form::label('password_confirmation', 'Confirm New Password:') }} <br>
                            <input type="password" name='password_confirmation' id='password_confirmation' value={{ $userinfo->password }}>
                        </div><br />

                        <div>
                            {{ Form::label('useraccess', 'Current Subscription Status:') }} <br>
                            {{ $access }}
                        </div><br />

                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
            </div> <!-- End Modal Body -->

            <div class="modal-footer">
                {{ Form::submit('Save', array('class' => ' btn btn-warning')) }}           
                <!-- Close the form -->
                {{ Form::close() }}
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
```

When I run the developer tools in the browser, I can see the auto insert

```
<form method="POST" action="http://dev.app.myapp.com/users" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="<TOKEN">

                <!-- Set hidden form element with userid embedded -->
                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="6">


                <!-- Display the username and profile Picture -->
                <h2><center>johndoe123</center></h2>
                <br><br>

                <!-- 2 Column Form to change user information and display current status -->
                <div class="container col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="row col-md-3">
                        <div>
                            <label for="givenname">First Name:</label> <br>
                            <input type="text" name="givenname" id="givenname" value="John">
                        </div><br>

                        <div>
                            <label for="surname">Last Name:</label> <br>
                            <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname" value="Doe">
                        </div><br>


                        <div>
                            <label for="email">Email Address:</label> <br>
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="johndoe@notarealemail.com">
                        </div><br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row col-md-3">
                        <div>
                            <label for="password">New Password:</label> <br>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="Encrypted Password String">
                        </div><br>

                        <div>
                            <label for="password_confirmation">Confirm New Password:</label> <br>
                            <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" value="Encrypted Password String">
                        </div><br>

                        <div>
                            <label for="useraccess">Current Subscription Status:</label> <br>
                            User                            </div><br>

                    </div>
                </div>
                            </form>

<div class="modal-footer">
            <input class=" btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Save">           
            <!-- Close the form -->
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Just looks like bad mark-up to me. You should open the form outside of the `modal-body` div and then close it outside (at the bottom) of the `modal-footer` div. So essentially the form is wrapping *everything*.

Comment: Tried moving the open form to the modal-header, and that just makes it insert the close form into the modal-header as well... Don't understand why its auto closing the form.. I have other modals using exactly the same markup, where I am opening the form in the body and closing it in the footer and it's working as expected.

Comment: If you use "view page source" instead, is it still there?

Comment: Please post too the other similar markup, maybe you've overlooked a subtle detail making the difference.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your mark-up is lacking proper structure. You begin the `<form>` in some element, then close it inside another element.

Check out the page source (`ALT+CMD+U` on Mac). You will notice `</form>` exactly where you originally put `Form::close()` (inside `<div class="modal-footer">`).

That position, however, is invalid mark-up, as I mentioned before. The browser doesn't know exactly what you want, but it will try to come to a conclusion, so it correctly moves `</form>` down one level.

**What you are seeing in *developer tools* is not what was printed out by Laravel, but actually how the browser interpreted your invalid mark-up.**

A solution for this specific case: move `Form::close()` after `<div class="modal-footer">`.